# How do I set the default value for a column?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlplus

Note the table below.  I am wanting to set the default value for the newly created `BEST_SELLER` column to `"N"`.
How do I go about doing that?

```
Create Table Mystery
(Book_Code Char(4) Primary Key,
 Title Varchar2(40),
 Publisher_Code Char(2),
 Price Number(4,2))
```

Comment: IMO The title of this question should be changed to reflect the nature of the beast, for posterity.

Comment: What SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL PLUS.  I HAVE ALREADY CREATED THE COLUMN BEST_SELLER...

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but looking at the name of your table (Mystery), I get the uncomfortable feeling that you may have different tables for different kinds of books.  That will most likely give you headaches down the road.  A better approach might be one table with a GenreCode column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic [MySQL Alter Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command

If the column doesn't exist:

```
alter table Mystery add column BEST_SELLER enum('N','Y') default 'N';
```

and if column exists:

```
alter table Mystery alter column BEST_SELLER set default 'N';
```

Answer (score 5):

I am adding a second answer because of your response to my first answer.  This answer applies since:

1. You are using Oracle, and
2. You have already created the table, so you need to use "ALTER TABLE" syntax.

Please find enclosed the following:

```
alter table
    mystery
modify
    BEST_SELLER char(1) DEFAULT 'N'
```

Please modify the type `char(1)` to whatever the column actually is.  After running this query to correct the table, you will need to issue a second query to update the existing rows, such as:

```
UPDATE 
    mystery 
SET 
    BEST_SELLER = 'N' 
WHERE 
       BEST_SELLER = '' 
    OR BEST_SELLER IS NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will that then populate existing rows?

Comment: Nothing at first, you will need to issue a general purpose update query like: `UPDATE mystery SET BEST_SELLER = 'N' WHERE BEST_SELLER = '' OR BEST_SELLER IS NULL` (that's based on my knowledge of MySQL syntax, although I think it's generic enough to carry to oracle), but the default value should future-proof you in this situation.

Comment: What if you haven't created the table yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you added the column after the table was created you can do something similar with the alter statement.

[alter](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_alter.asp)